# Checksum on slides content

Tags: algorithm, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, checksum

I have trainings which contain slides. When user request to load the training, all its slides are copy to view_slides table.  But I don't want to copy those slides on each training load, so I want to check if training owner changed something on his slides. If he was, I will replace copy of slides by new ones.

The question is - how to check if something changed? I think, that I should load all slides content and check if there were changes, but how can I do it efficiently? Can I use checksum like for example MD5?

Comment: a checksum is sufficient when looking for text changes

Comment: thanks, but is MD5 is sufficient for that purpose or should I use something stronger like for example SHA-1 or SHA-2?

Comment: There's much known about collissions in MD5 and SHA-1, and not much about collissions in SHA-2 (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Comparison_of_SHA_functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-security purposes, all the usual hash functions, such as MD5 or SHA, are fine. The problem with collisions for MD5, say, is related to attacks where such collisions are carefully crafted, not to a situation where you use a hash function to detect changed content.

Also, you can hash any content, not only text. If the slides are PPTs you can hash the PPT files themselves, i.e. read the binary content of a file, run it through a hash function, and save the hash value, or some part of it.

Comment: but if collision can happen using MD5 or SHA, how high is the probability of situation where one slide, after changes will generate same hash?

Comment: Collisions can happen with all hash functions, but they happen with so low probability that it doesn't matter. The issue about collisions with cryptographic hash functions is always related to computer security, not to hashing random content for the purpose of fingerprinting it.

Comment: The probability that two slides have the same MD5 hash value is 2 raised to the power of -128. Read: never happens.